# Algorithm for synchronisation of ordered collections

Tags: algorithm, sorting, data-synchronization

The problem is i need to maintain an order in a collection of many items. The order is not based on any attribute of the data but chosen from outside the data structure (for example manually by the user via drag and drop). Because of the used synchronization between computers i can only modify attributes in the item (using timestamps on the attribute changes to solve conflicts - last edit wins). I'm not allowed to send a list of items or item identifier.

So i thought about adding a key to each item and setting a sort key as the middle key  "(left + right)/2" whenever an item moved to this location. Unfortuantely this works perfect in theory with rational numbers but not in computers with floating points because they would reach their precision limit soon.

So how can i do this with minimal size strings?  Or is there any other algorithm to use here.

I remember seeing a C++ video on youtube recently, something like generatic half-lings library but can't find it again. At the time i didn't realize that this is solving my problem.

Comment: Is there any upper limit on the number of items?

Comment: Please clarify "manually by the user via drag and drop". What is being dropped? Sounds like you're making it sort based on that, and you're making a GUI? So there are multiple GUIs running you'd like to keep in sync?

Comment: This just means that there is no explicit sort criteria to derive from the data itself. 

It depends if the user sorted it interactively in a way he liked and locally i just store the array. But as this is using a Peer2Peer synchronization to mobile devices i need to sync this order.

Comment: The upper limit of the items can be assumed to be one million.
I can do a complete new key assignment after a synchronization to both sides but it shouldn't happen too often. I was just thinking back about the old days of Basic computing where you used line numbers with 10 step increments. Where you have a few shoots to insert/change lines.

Answer (score 0):

A reasonable solution for this problem comes from a paper called "[Two Algorithms For Maintaining Order In A List](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/%7Esleator/papers/maintaining-order.pdf)", by Dietz and Sleator.

The implementation is simple if the number of labels you can use (M) is more than the square of the number of items in the list:

1. When you insert a new item, its label is the midpoint between its neighbors;
2. When there is no space between the neighbors, you have to relabel a portion of the list.  Expand outward from the insertion point until you get a sublist where the number of possible labels that it spans is greater than the square of the number of items, and then relabel that sublist evenly.

The paper proves that the amortized number of label changes is O(log n) per insertion.

This can solve your ordering problem using operations that you say you can do, but doesn't necessarily solve your synchronization problems, i.e., maintaining consistency across multiple users. I don't know what kind of synchronization primitives you have available.